# What to pass as threshold for Naive Bayes Classifier in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, naivebayes, roc

I'm trying to make a ROC curve for my model while using a Naive Bayes Classifier. To do this, I need to change the value of the threshold for my classifier. The way I interpreted it, a list must be passed with the value for the threshold of each category. So if i had two categories, and t is the threshold I want to set (0 <= t <= 1), then I would have to pass a list like this: [1-t, t].

Anyways, when i tried doing the ROC curve, I got this:

[image: ROC curve]

Given the result, my idea was that the idea I had for the theshold might have been wrong, so I went to check the [documentation for the Naive Bayes Classifier](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes.html#naivebayes). But when I finally found an example i dont get what the criteria is for the parameter:

```
nb = nb.setThresholds([0.01, 10.00])
```

Does anyone know what must be passed to the threshold? Supose I want the theshold to be set at 0.7 (if the probability is over 0.7 i want the prediction to be 1), what should i pass to the threshold parameter?

Comment: I don't understand your question. A ROC curve shows all thresholds. You don't want to set them yourself. And actually your ROC curve looks ok.

Comment: @Calimo I know the roc curve shows al thresholds. The question goes on the matter of what is the parameter to pass to the NaiveBayes classifier of Pyspark.

On other matters, do you think that's an acceptable ROC curve. It seems to me that the points (aside from the first and last) look like a straight condensed line, and I'm not really getting that curve I'm supposed to be getting.

Comment: So is your question about the ROC curve or about setThresholds? Please only ask one clear question per post. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/147320

Answer (score 0):

As it says in `pyspark.ml`'s documentation for `NaiveBayes` under the `thresholds` parameter:

> The class with largest value p/t is predicted, where p is the original
> probability of that class and t is the class's threshold.

Therefore, thresholds can be thought of as handicaps on the probabilities. To keep it simple, in the case of binary classification, you can set the thresholds as a value in the range `[0, 1]`, such that they sum to `1`. This will get you the desired rule of "Classify as True if the probability is over threshold T, otherwise classify as False".

For your specific ask of a 0.7 probability threshold, this would look like:

```
nb = nb.setThresholds([0.3, 0.7])
```

assuming that the first entry is the threshold for `False` and the second value is the thresold for `True`. Using these thresholds, the model would classify a class with `False` and `True` probabilities `p_false` and `p_true` by taking the greater value out of `[p_false/0.3, p_true/0.7]`.

You can technically set the thresholds to any value. Just remember that the probability for class X will be divided by its respective threshold and compared against the other adjusted probabilities for the other classes.